# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql

Getting error when trying to connect from react client to express server using GraphQL API

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  to understand how a question should be asked here as your question has very little for us to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the express server end-point was given wrong.

changed

```
http://localhost/8000/graphql
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/graphql
```